# Updating SQLite database from MS SQL Server 2012 via Linked Server over Mapped Network Drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, mapped-drive, windows-networking

I'm trying to connect MS SQL Server 2012 to an SQLite database on another machine using Linked Server via a mapped network drive.

I've successfully set this up and I'm able to read from the SQLite database over the network.  However, when I try to update a value in the SQLite database using MS SQL Server, I get an error.  For example:

```
UPDATE [SQLiteDatabase]...[ValuesTable] SET Value = 150 WHERE Id = 4;
```

Then I get this error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "FastToolsDEM" returned message "unable to open database file (14)".
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "FastToolsDEM" could not UPDATE table "[FastToolsDEM]...[Numbers]".
```

If I copy the SQLite database to the local C: drive and make a local ODBC connection to the copied database, then it works successfully!

With regards to the mapped network drive, I am able to read, modify, write and delete without any problems system where MS SQL Server is installed using Windows Explorer and any other applications, which is expected because the share is set to "Read/Write" for "Everyone".

The problem I'm having is only specifically when trying to update the database from within MS SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

I've added some version information below:

SQLite 3.8.0.1

SQLite3 ODBC Driver 0.995.00.00

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3000.0

Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 11.0.3000.0

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514

Microsoft MSXML 3.0 4.0 6.0

Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0.7601.17514

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.1008

Operating System 6.1.7601

Windows 7 Enterprise

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used a different ODBC driver. Please check whether your system is 32 bit or 64 bit. The linked server will not work in 32 bit machines if you have used 64 bit driver.